# Another AJAX and Animation on load

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jscrollpane

I have a situation where content must be loaded using AJAX where a custom scroll plugin is also being used (jScrollpane). The content is displayed as columns that may or may not overflow horizontally on the page, the first page containing just a menu column.
The desired outcome is to have any existing column content slide away behind the menu and the loaded content (via AJAX call) slide into view.

At the moment I have something like

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
    destroyCustomScroll();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        success: function() {
        $(".contentCell:eq(" + parentColumnIndex + ")").after(data);
        }
        });
    createCustomScroll();
}
```

with the content page looking like this

```
<body>
  <div class="rowContainer">
    <div class="contentCell">
      <!-- content in whatever markup it comes in -->
      <a href="#">linkThatLoadsStuff</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

As I said earlier the desired outcome is to have the AJAX loaded content slide into view, and when another link is clicked for that content to slide out of view (and then maybe destroyed or maybe cached or whatever is planned later) and then the new content to slide into view.

Whilst hiding existing content is easy I have no idea how to slide the new content into view because the CSS required for the custom scroll plugin automagically puts the new content in its correct position (using display:table-cell on the contentCells).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain some easy way..

Comment: | <a> | <the first column on the page. I click the link. The content loads into a column and that 2nd column slides out from the side of the page to create a final page that looks like this | <a> | <b> |.
However I can't have the container exist in the DOM before the ajax call